# Why PHP header redirection is not working on mobile devices

Tags: php, redirect

I'm trying to redirect my website to a webpage called down.html if website status in my database is 0 (off).
It works fine on pc but when I test it on my phone it doesn't redirect and it stays at the same page I even tried different browsers but its the same

I'm running my website on a bluehost host and I'm using PHP for redirecting

```
<?php
ob_start();
include_once 'app/webload.php';
$obj = new main();
$settings = $obj->settings();
if($settings[0]['status'] == '0'){
    header("Location:down.html");
}
```

It works on pc but not on phone

Comment: Do you have `exit;` after the call to `header()`?

Comment: i tested it but it just shows a white page

Comment: Try to add a space after `Location:`

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` to see if any errors are generated.

Comment: It could be that your mobile browser is so old that it can't recognise relative paths.